# Why is my Javascript only working at the first row of the table?

Tags: javascript

Hey Guys im having a problem with my javascript code. It only works on the first row of the table and not the rest.

```html
<div id="Q2">
  <table>
    <tr class="headtop">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Section</th>
      <th>3rd Quarter Grades</th>
      <th>4th Quarter Grades</th>
      <th> Semester Average</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
$sql = $conn2->query("SELECT  Name, Section, Initial1, Initial2, Final, id FROM " .$subid. " ORDER BY Name");
if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())  {
echo "<form method='POST' action='savesem1.php'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" .str_replace('!', ' ', str_replace('_', ' ', $row["Name"])). "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row["Section"]. "</td>";
echo "<td><input  name='I1sem2G11' id='I1sem2G11' onChange='CD();' value='" .$row["Initial1"]. "'/></td>";
echo "<td><input  name='I2sem2G11' id='I2sem2G11' onChange='CD();' value='" .$row["Initial2"]. "'/></td>";
echo "<td><input  name='Finalsem2G11' id='Finalsem2G11'  value='" .$row["Final"]. "'  /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='submitcardsem2G11' id='submitcardsem2G11' class='btnupdate' value='Save Changes'></td>";   
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='idsem2G11' id='idsem2G11' value='" .$row["id"]. "'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='y' id='y' value='" .$subid. "'/></td>";    
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>"; 
}
} else { echo ""; }
?>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is the javascript its purpose is to get the average of the two inputs and put it in another input

```js
function CD() {
  var C = $("#I1sem2G11").val();
  var D = $("#I2sem2G11").val();
  var CD = (+C + +D) / 2;
  document.getElementById("Finalsem2G11").value = CD;
}
```

Comment: _It only works on the first row of the table and not the rest..._ What does that mean?

Comment: If this is NOT a PHP question,. then click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] with ONLY HTML and script. No PHP

Comment: Your problem is duplicate ID

Comment: There are a few issues with this code. First, are you using Mysqli or PDO? if you aren't you should be. Second, you shouldn't really be passing in a variable directly in to your query, especially if it's from user submitted data. Third, you shouldn't have a form inside a table tag. Finally ID's should be unique. This could well be the reason it isn't working. Consider using classes instead?

Comment: This is my first time posting a question in stack overflow. I did not expect it to be answered so quickly. Im sorry if my code is really messy. I use PDO code in the savesem1.php when the data is inserted in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is duplicate IDs

I am not super happy with the `<form>` wrapping `<tr>`s either but it works

```js
$("#tb").on("input", "input", function() {
  const $row = $(this).closest("tr");
  const C = $row.find("[name=I1sem2G11]").val();
  const D = $row.find("[name=I2sem2G11]").val();
  const CD = (+C + +D) / 2;
  console.log(C,D,CD)
  $row.find("[name=Finalsem2G11]").val(CD);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Q2">
  <table>
    <tr class="headtop">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Section</th>
      <th>3rd Quarter Grades</th>
      <th>4th Quarter Grades</th>
      <th> Semester Average</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="tb">
      <form method='POST' action='savesem1.php'>
        <tr>
          <td>Name1</td>
          <td>Section1</td>
          <td><input name='I1sem2G11' value='10' /></td>
          <td><input name='I2sem2G11' value='21' /></td>
          <td><input name='Finalsem2G11' id='Finalsem2G11' value='0' /></td>
          <td><input type='submit' name='submitcardsem2G11' class='btnupdate' value='Save Changes'></td>
          <td><input type='hidden' name='idsem2G11' value='id1' /></td>
          <td><input type='hidden' name='y' id='y' value='subid1' /></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
      <form method='POST' action='savesem1.php'>
        <tr>
          <td>Name2</td>
          <td>Section2</td>
          <td><input name='I1sem2G11' value='11' /></td>
          <td><input name='I2sem2G11' value='22' /></td>
          <td><input name='Finalsem2G11' value='0' /></td>
          <td><input type='submit' name='submitcardsem2G11' class='btnupdate' value='Save Changes'></td>
          <td><input type='hidden' name='idsem2G11' value='id2' /></td>
          <td><input type='hidden' name='y' id='y' value='subid2' /></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: _I am not super happy with the <form> wrapping <tr>.._ +1

Comment: Thanks mplungjan this saved me alot of time.